# How to find the value using attributes within GridView in asp.net using JS?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView

```
  <asp:GridView ID="Gvr" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="disable" runat="server"   CommandName="disable" OnClientClick="return enableOrDisable()"  
             data-active='<%#Eval("isActive") %>'> </asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In that GridView's Link Button, Ihave an attribute called  data-active. I get some value for it 0 or 1. But I want to access its value using JS. How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
<script>
function enableOrDisable(){
var isActive = $('data-active').val(); // here it says undefined. I want to get the value of data-active attribute
        if (isactive === 1) { alert('Are you sure you want to disable'); }
        else { alert('Are you sure you want to enable'); }
}
```

But it's not working

Comment: try $('#disable').prop('data-active') or $('#disable').attr('data-active') data-active is a property of element disable not the element itself.

Comment: Not working. It says "undefined"

Comment: whats the id of element <asp:Linkbutton> when you inspect in developer tools???

Comment: It says ContentPlaceHolder1_Gvr_disable_0 as the Id

Comment: <asp:LinkButton CssClass='disable-link'> add a unique class to this link and then access it $('.disable-link').prop('data-active') or $('.disable-link').attr('data-active'). I hope it works.

Comment: Nope. Still undefined.

Comment: are you sure you have value in this <%#Eval("isActive") %> from server side ???

Comment: do you see evaluated value in link button when you inspect that element via dev tools?

Comment: @maverickosama92 Yes I am sure. I get its value from server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your markup and your javascript in a way, that you pass your element directly:

markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="disable" runat="server"   CommandName="disable" OnClientClick="return enableOrDisable(this)" data-active='<%#Eval("isActive") %>'> </asp:LinkButton>
```

javascript (also change your typo: `isActive` instead of `isactive`!):

```js
function enableOrDisable(sender) {
    var isActive = $(sender).attr('data-active'); // here it says undefined. I want to get the value of data-active attribute
    if (isActive === 1) { alert('Are you sure you want to disable'); }
    else { alert('Are you sure you want to enable'); }
}
```